# How to add json value inside ng-model in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div data-ng-repeat="credentialsdata in credentialsdatas">
    <div data-inline-validate data-error="{{ credentialsdata.key }}">
    <label>{{ credentialsdata.key }}<i class="text-error">*</i></label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="datasource.{{ credentialsdata.key }}" placeholder="{{ credentialsdata.key }}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But here it is throwing error

```
 data-ng-model="datasource.{{ credentialsdata.key }}"
```

Comment: Just remove the {{}}? Please tell the error and what you want to happen if you want to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use binding in this case, just try javascript bracket notation syntax:

```
data-ng-model="datasource[credentialsdata.key]"
```

Comment: $scope.datasource.credential.key[] ,is it pssible to take this values like this in controller

Comment: @prash: I don't understand the `[]` at the end. What are you trying to do? Inside your controller, if you know the property name and don't need to get the property dynamically, you could use dot notation syntax.

Comment: on submit i need to take all these input box values and send to service

Comment: @prash: as I understand from your code. Your `datasource` holds all values of your inputs. Why don't just send the `datasource` to the service?